# Cómo guardar datos de una consulta en un campo textbox en c#

Tags: c#

Buenas Tardes.

Estoy trabajando con una respuesta que me dieron a una pregunta que hice la otra vez y me gustaría modificarla, este es el código:

```
public static string ObtenerConnectionString()
{
    return @"Data Source=*****; Initial Catalog=ZonaFranca; user id=*****;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
}



private void txt_documento_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        string connstring = ObtenerConnectionString();

        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string query = @"select Codigo,Descripcion from zf_TipoDoc 
                            where ltrim(rtrim(Codigo)) = @codigo";
            var comando = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            comando.Parameters.AdWithValue("@codigo", txt_documento.Text);

            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            cmbbox_documento.ValueMember = "Codigo";
            cmbbox_documento.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";
            cmbbox_documento.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
}
```

en base a este código, como puedo modificarlo para que el resultado de la consulta pueda agregarlo a un campo textbox? Que pueda poner el Codigo de la consulta en un textbox_codigo por ejemplo.

Sé que debe ser algo simple pero soy un poco principiante en c#.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria algo como esto

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    conn.Open();

    string query = @"select Codigo,Descripcion from zf_TipoDoc 
                    where ltrim(rtrim(Codigo)) = @codigo";
    var comando = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    comando.Parameters.AdWithValue("@codigo", txt_documento.Text);

    var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

    if(reader.Read()){
        textbox_codigo.Text = reader["Codigo"].ToString();
    }

}
```

Como veras basicamente usas el `SqlDataReader` para obtener solo una de las rows de la consulta

En este caso asigne solo el codigo, pero podrias tambien obtener la descripcion

---

Si solo retornarias el codigo entonces se podria optimizar aun mas

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    conn.Open();

    string query = @"select ISNULL(Codigo, '') from zf_TipoDoc 
                    where ltrim(rtrim(Codigo)) = @codigo";
    var comando = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    comando.Parameters.AdWithValue("@codigo", txt_documento.Text);

    var codigo = Convert.ToString(comando.ExecuteScalar());

    textbox_codigo.Text = codigo;

}
```

Use el `ISNULL` por sino ha registros con ese codigo para que retorne un valor por defecto

Comment: ok, me funcionó a la primera. Muchas gracias